# Is facebook/react-native-fbsdk a type of Authorization Code Grant Flow with PKCE?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using these packages which do not require client id and client secret key to be stored in the react native app client side. I would like to know if the packages mentioned are using the pattern of Authorization Code Grant Flow with PKCE?

- Facebook fbsdk React Native https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk
- Google Signin React Native https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!!
Please describe your question in more detail with more insights like explaining the actual task you want to accomplish, add you erroneous code snippet and what all resolutions you actually tried already to eradicate the issue
Make note to add corresponding tags and format your code before pasting here.
For more details visit StackOverflow's guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Signin React Native https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin you can use `serverAuthCode` from [userInfo](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin#3-userinfo) object.

I'm also looking for the implementation of this flow for `react-native-fbsdk`, but didn't find.